# Как сконвертировать один объект в другой с использованием Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть такая сущность:

```
public class Test {
    private long field;

    public long getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(long field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Из БД мне приходит список таких объектов:

```
List<Test> testList = dao.getAll();
```

Также у меня есть другие объекты:

```
public class Entries {
    private List<Entry> entry;

    public List<Entry> getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(List<Entry> entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }
}
```

и

```
public class Entry {
    private int field;

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Я хочу с помощью Stream API и операции `map` преобразовать список объектов `Test` в `Entries`, т.е. поле `field` из объекта `Test` должно просетиться в поле `field` объекта `Entry`, и на выходе должен получиться `Entries`, содержащий список `entry`. Как это можно сделать?

**UPDATE:**

Без стримов я бы сделал так:

```
Entries entries = new Entries();
List<Entry> entriesList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Test test : testList) {
    Entry entry = new Entry();
    entry.setField(test.getField());
    entriesList.add(entry);
}
entries.setEntry(entriesList);
```

Comment: Название метода `getEntry` подразумевает возвращение одной сущности `Entry`. Для возвращения списка логичнее назвать метод `getEntries`. Однако так как класс сам по себе называется `Entries`, то можно ограничиться просто названием `get`, особенно если других get-методов в нём не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявить в `Entry` конструктор принимающий `Test` и передать его в метод `map`:

```
public class Entry {
    private int field;

    public Entry(Test source) {
        setField(source.getField());
    }

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}

List<Entry> entries = testList
                        .stream()
                        .map(Entry::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**UPDATE:** Не знаю зачем нужна обёртка `Entries`, но если её чуть-чуть довести до ума, то можно создавать не отходя от потока.

```
class Entries {
    private List<Entry> data;

    public Entries() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addEntry(Entry entry) {
        data.add(entry);
    }

    public void addEntries(Entries entries) {
        data.addAll(entries.get());
    }

    public List<Entry> get() {
        return data;
    }
}

Entries entries = testList
                    .stream()
                    .map(Entry::new)
                    .collect(Collector.of(
                        Entries::new,
                        (acc, val) -> acc.addEntry(val),
                        (l, r) -> {
                            l.addEntries(r);
                            return l;
                        },
                        acc -> acc));
```

Comment: Через стримы я попробывал сделать вот так:                                  
       Entries entries = new Entries();
        List<Entry>  entriesList = testList.stream()
                                            .map(ObjectConverter::getEntry)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        entries.setEntry(entriesList);  Не знаю насколько это верно.

Comment: Можно и так, но зачем?

Comment: `Entries` из данного объекта я потом должен сформировать `XML` файл, он для этого нужен

Comment: Тогда дополнение ответы может оказаться полезным.

Comment: Просто насколько это правильно, в конструктор `Entry` передавать какой-то другой объект + вызывать в нем сеттер. Может глупости говорю, но я только учусь.

Comment: Обычное дело. [Вот](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l167), например, конструктор `ArrayList` принимает `Collection` для копирования в себя его элементов.